# View list item page and associated approval tasks webpart

Tags: web-part, task-list, workflow-tasks-list

I have custom list with an InfoPath form and a Nintex approval workflow associated with it.

**What I want to achieve:** I would like approvers to be able to see their pending approval tasks for the item in a webpart when viewing the form.

**What I've done so far:** I added a webpart to the displayifs.aspx page to show the Workflow Tasks list. I created a view to filter it by:

- Assigned to = [me]
- Status <> "Completed"

The webpart shows then all pending approval tasks for the person viewing the page. I would like to filter it further and show only tasks associated with the currently viewed item, but I can't find any connections to use. Is this achievable OOTB? Am I missing something?